# How to prove the following claim about Pseudoinverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For real symmetric matrices $K$ and $\hat{K}$, if $u^{T}{K}u\le u^{T}\hat{K}u\le C u^{T}{K}u$ for all $u$ in the row space of $K$, then
$u^{T}{K^{+}}u\ge u^{T}\hat{K}^{+}u\ge  u^{T}{K^{+}}u/C$ for all $u$ in the row space of $K$, where $K^{+}$ is the Pseudoinverse of $K$.

I found this claim in the paper 
http://arxiv.org/abs/1407.1289.
Is there a simple proof for this?

Comment: I assume that $K$ and $\hat{K}$ are supposed to be at least hermitian? This surely isn't true for all matrices.

Comment: yes they are real symmetric